# Pointers to array differ in STL vs regular for loops

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, for-loop, foreach

I have two loops that iterate over an array of about 20 bools one after the other and print the memory address of each one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    printf("%p\n", &_boolArray[i]);
}
for (bool b : _boolArray) {
    b = true;
    printf("%p\n", &b);
}
```

I would expect the output to be exactly the same for both arrays.  What I got was something a little different:

```
0x102eeefb0
0x102eeefb1
0x102eeefb2
0x102eeefb3
0x102eeefb4
0x102eeefb5
...
0x7fff5ce8b9bf
0x7fff5ce8b9bf
0x7fff5ce8b9bf
0x7fff5ce8b9bf
0x7fff5ce8b9bf
```

I know there are better ways to fill an array (std::fill for one), but I still want to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a copy of b in second for loop every time, should pass by reference

```
 for (bool &b : _boolArray) {
       //  ^^^ reference to original element
    b = true;
    printf("%p\n", &b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `for` loop copies the array values to `b` which is at another location (constant one) that's why your output look like that

This is the right way to do it

```
for(bool &b:_boolArray) // Reference to memory
{
    printf("%p\n",&b);
}
```